# How to show the dependency between the inputs and outputs of a component on the N^2 diagram?

Tags: openmdao

In OpenMDAO 2.3 in components all inputs and outputs are connected on the N^2 diagram (marked with black boxes), even if the value of a given outputs does not depend on all inputs, or not all partial derivatives where declared for it. Is it possible to show only the real connections?

As an example in the actuator disk problem in the ExplicitComponent "a_disk" the output "Ct" (and its partial derivative) does not depend on the input "Area". Despite this on the N^2 diagram there is a black box between these variables.

[N^2 diagram of the actuator disc problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZEZCE.png)

Answer (score 0):

As of OpenMDAO 2.3 the N2 diagram doesn't get information about the partial derivative connectivity. We have thought about using that before, but just haven't gotten around do it. Pull requests welcome though!